# ios how to keep data for application after update it from the store

Tags: ios

Can I save data for my application in case when it is updated from app store. For example I have sqlite database in the version 1.0 then I have updated my app to version 1.1 how can I save this database in my document directory without overwritten.

Comment: same thing when we coding in to xcode and text app in device. while we edit code and again run app in to device without delete app the contain of app are not removed. so this is a samething that you are asking and given answer are True that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of your app's directories are not overwritten when you update your app from the app store. So you don't have to worry about losing the data when a user updates the app.

Only if the app is deleted first are the directories deleted.

Comment: how can I simulate this process without using app store to check it? i mean if I rerun app with new version in xcode is it the same?

Comment: Yes it is. Try it and you'll see for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Your documents will stay where they are - unless the user deletes the app before updating.

> **Files Saved During App Updates**
>
> Files Saved During App Updates When a user downloads an app update,
>   iTunes installs the update in a new app directory. It then moves the
>   user’s data files from the old installation over to the new app
>   directory before deleting the old installation. Files in the following
>   directories are guaranteed to be preserved during the update process:
>
> - `<Application_Home>/Documents`
> - `<Application_Home>/Library`
>
> Although files in other user directories may also be moved over, you
>   should not rely on them being present after an update.

Here is what apple says more about it - [Ref link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html)